# Show details in Repeater control using Entity Framework (code first approach) in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

How can i get data for ASp.net webform using Entity Framework Code first Approach

I need to show employee List from Emp table on a Emp.aspx page using reapeter control

I am new to EF and trying to learn EF for asp.net webforms

So far i have created following App_Code Folder

```
App_Code
    DBClass
        Dept.cs
        Emp.cs
        EmployeeDBContent.cs
        EmpRepository.cs
```

Code for all the files

**Dept.cs**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Dept
    /// </summary>
 namespace empNS
{   
public class Dept
    {
        //Scalar properties
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        //Navigation Property
        public List<Emp> Emp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Emp.cs**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for EmpRepository
    /// </summary>
namespace empNS
{
    public class EmpRepository
    {
        public List<Dept> GetDepartments()
        {
            EmployeeDBContext empDBContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
            return empDBContext.Dept.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**EmployeeDBContext.cs**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for EmployeeDBContext
    /// </summary>
namespace empNS
{
    public class EmployeeDBContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Dept> Dept { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Emp> Emp { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**EmpRepository.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for EmpRepository
/// </summary>
```

namespace empNS
{
    public class EmpRepository
    {
        public static List GetEmployees()
    {
        EmployeeDBContext empDBContext = new EmployeeDBContext();
        return empDBContext.Emp.ToList();
    }
    }

}

I am not sure how i can show empployee list on `Emp.aspx` page using repeater control

**Emp.aspx code**

```
 <h1>Employee List</h1>
        <asp:Repeater ID="empList" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%#Eval("ID") %></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("FirstName") %></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("LastName") %></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace empNS
{
    public partial class Emp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //UPDATED CODE
        rptEmpList.DataSource = EmpRepository.GetEmployees();
        rptEmpList.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

How can i call `GetDepartments()` function from `EmpRepository.cs` so to display employee list in repeater control.

I am totally new to this and have not been able to find an simple example which can bind repeater control using code first approach to display information.
Any help or pointer to tutorial will be helpful.

Comment: Did you pick webforms yourself or was this dictated by employer/professor? You would get better examples of integrating EF with web applications if you learned ASP.NET MVC or Core.

Comment: I need to modify old webform application and parts of it need to be done using EF..

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a `List` directly to a Repeater. Just make sure you point to the correct namespace.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        empList.DataSource = EmpRepository.GetDepartments();
        empList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

And since you are binding a class to a Repeater, it is easier to make it stronly typed. THen you can access the properties directly.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="empList" runat="server" ItemType="YourNameSpace.Dept">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Item.ID %></td>
            <td><%# Item.FirstName %></td>
            <td><%# Item.LastName  %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But it looks like the Employees are a property of a Department. So if you want those you either have to use a nested Repeater, loop all the departments to get the employees, or select a department for the Repeater.

This will get the List of employees for the first department

```
empList.DataSource = EmpRepository.GetDepartments()[0].Emp;
```

A nested Repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="empList" runat="server" ItemType="YourNameSpace.Dept">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:Repeater ID="empListNested" runat="server" ItemType="YourNameSpace.Dept.Emp" DataSource='<%# Item.Emp %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: `empList.DataSource = EmpRepository.GetDepartments(); I get an error on this line an Object is required for the non-static methodEmpRepository.GetDepartment()` I am also using NameSpace empNS in `EmpRepository` and accessing same in emp.asp.cs file.

Comment: Maybe you have to make your classes `static`. The rest is just pointing to the correct class `empNS.classA.ClassB`

Comment: after making get class as static `public static List<Dept> GetDepartments()` and updating code as it doesnt pull any records from database